Outliner slows animation preview in 3d viewport
I played animation preview in 3d viewport but when outliner area is displayed animation preview is slowed.
if I hide outliner, animation preview gets faster.
Outliner does something useless when animation preview is played. Is there anyway to optimize it? I need outliner but when animation preview is played I don't need outliner to update something and use up CPU and GPU powers.
I use python script which hides outliners when animation is playing but I can't stop outliners from updating itself? I even don't touch and see the outliner when I play animation.

In the timeline you can set the playback to active window only.

it doesn't solve the problem. when outliner exists somewhere  it consumes CPU resource like animation preview in quad view window uses quadruple resource. If I hide outliner, preview FPS increases.

I don't think any settings exist for what you want to do and I don't think it's possible to optimize performance without altering the source code if at all. It seems like hiding the Outliner with Python is a decent solution. You can write an operator and assign a hotkey to whatever you need to do to hide it. Why is that not good enough?

I use handlers and manually hiding outliners by script which almighty Chat GPT made for me, but I simply don't understand why outliner keeps consuming PC resource when it shouldn't.

This is the script I use. 2nd script's handler just simply replaces Outliner with Python Console panel temporarily when animation plays.
manually hiding script
import bpy
for area in bpy.context.window.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'OUTLINER':
        area.type = 'CONSOLE'
    elif area.type == 'CONSOLE':
        area.type = 'OUTLINER'

handler script
import bpy

# Define handler functions
def handler_pre_func(scene):
    """Hide the Outliner when animation playback starts."""
    for area in bpy.context.window.screen.areas:
        if area.type == 'OUTLINER':
            area.type = 'CONSOLE'  # Temporarily switch to CONSOLE view
    print("Animation started, Outliner hidden.")

def handler_post_func(scene):
    """Restore the Outliner when animation playback stops."""
    for area in bpy.context.window.screen.areas:
        if area.type == 'CONSOLE':
            area.type = 'OUTLINER'  # Restore the original Outliner
    print("Animation stopped, Outliner restored.")

def remove_handler():
    """Remove the specified handlers."""
    # Check by function name
    bpy.app.handlers.animation_playback_pre[:] = [
        handler for handler in bpy.app.handlers.animation_playback_pre if handler.__name__ != handler_pre_func.__name__
    ]
    bpy.app.handlers.animation_playback_post[:] = [
        handler for handler in bpy.app.handlers.animation_playback_post if handler.__name__ != handler_post_func.__name__
    ]
    print("Removed handler_pre_func and handler_post_func.")

def register_handler():
    """Add the handlers."""
    bpy.app.handlers.animation_playback_pre.append(handler_pre_func)
    bpy.app.handlers.animation_playback_post.append(handler_post_func)
    print("Registered handler_pre_func and handler_post_func.")

def toggle_handlers():
    """Toggle the registration or removal of handlers."""
    # Check if already registered by function name
    pre_registered = any(handler.__name__ == handler_pre_func.__name__ for handler in bpy.app.handlers.animation_playback_pre)
    post_registered = any(handler.__name__ == handler_post_func.__name__ for handler in bpy.app.handlers.animation_playback_post)

    if pre_registered or post_registered:
        remove_handler()  # Remove if already registered
    else:
        register_handler()  # Add if not registered

# Toggle on execution
if __name__ == "__main__":
    toggle_handlers()

